# Writing from textbox in Form2 to Datagridview in Form1

Tags: c#, winforms

I am still new to C# so please bear with me.

I have Form1 with a `DataGridView` and a `Button`. This button opens `Form2`.

`Form2` contains a `TextBox` and a `Button` that closes `Form2`.

I need to write the text from the `TextBox` in `Form2` into the first cell of the `DataGridView` in Form1. In the application I am developing, there is other data already in the `DataGridView` in `Form1`.

I have uploaded the Visual Studio 2010 file [here](https://www.yousendit.com/download/TEhXSkhZWlRiV3cwTWRVag).

EDIT:

Please look at this screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

I seem to instantiating a new `Form1` when I don't want to.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Please do not post code to 3rd party services. Place the relevant part of your source code directly into your question.

Comment: Ondrej Ttucny: I've added the code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Form2` to instantiate (again) the main form (`Form1`).

A more appropriate approach is to open the auxiliary form containing the text-box as a modal-dialog window, and let the opener form (`Form1`) access the text entered by the user at `Form2` instance.

Here below are described the changes needed:

**`Form2` changes:**

1.- Add a new class member to store the string that is to be introduced in the text-box `textBox1`.

```
public String textFromTextBox = null;
```

2.- Add code to your OK button's clic event-handler, so that you store in the new class member `textFromTextBox` the value introduced in the text-box:

3.- Last, in the same clic event-handling code set the `DialogResult` property to `DialogResult.OK`.

The `Form2` code would look like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    [...]

    // This class member will store the string value 
    // the user enters in the text-box
    public String textFromTextBox = null;

    [...]

    // This is the event-handling code that you must place for
    // the OK button.
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textFromTextBox = this.textBox1.Text;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

**`Form1` changes**

1.- In your button with the label "Enter Text" (that is actually missing in your code), in the `Click` event-handler put the code necessary to open the `Form2` as a modal `Dialog`.

2.- Set the cell value in your data-grid accordingly by recovering the value stored in the `Form2`'s `textFromTextBox` member.

3.- Finally dispose your `Form2` instance.

```
   Form2 myFormWithATextBox = new Form2();

   if (myFormWithATextBox.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = myFormWithATextBox.textFromTextBox;
   }
   myFormWithATextBox.Dispose();
```

Take into account that your main form is `Form1` while `Form2` it is just an auxiliary form control, it should not take much control on the flow of your application, and therefore not assume the responsibility of instantiating the main form.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variable from Form to another by create another contractor that accept parameters as the following:-

1) go to form1 then create another contractor:

```
    public Form1(string myString)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (myString != null)
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = myString;
    }
```

2) go to form2 and under the button write this code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1(textBox1.Text);
        frm1.ShowDialog();
    }
```

[Here you are your application after modification](http://www.mediafire.com/?28dde3cjzg8b3po)